# Как узнать через код, поддерживает ли целевой компилятор С++ тип long long int?

Tags: c++, кроссплатформенность, препроцессор

Я пишу кроссплатформенную библиотеку. Код будет компилироваться под разные платформы разными компиляторами, и, возможно, некоторые из них не поддерживают целые числа 64 битной разрядности. Хотелось бы через директивы препроцессора обработать критические участки кода с их использованием, но как это сделать? Есть ли какой-нибудь `#ifdef __LONG_LONG_INT_T__`, чтобы узнать, поддерживает ли компилятор тот или иной примитивный тип?

Comment: В своем Makefile вы делаете вход `configure`, исполнение которого генерит файл `config.h` (больше деталей см. в ответе @eri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно такая проверка делается программой `./configure`. Напиши скрипт который создаст файлик с [объявлением long long](https://github.com/sloede/cxx11tests/blob/master/src/long-long.cpp) и небольшим тестом. Этот файлик компилируется (и исполняется, если тест этого требует). Если тест не прошел, то записываешь переменную в хидер или в мэйкфайл.

Для проектов на autoconf используется макрос AC_COMPILE_IFELSE https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Running-the-Compiler.html

Comment: Это правильный ответ.

Comment: @avp тут даже галочка была полдня.)

Comment: Да, тут теперь многовато стало голосовать совсем не разбирающихся в теме (и похоже у них силен стадный инстинкт)

Comment: Ответ правильный, но галочка подняла его наверх и приманила  голосовать против, поэтому я её снял. Надеюсь на понимание.

Comment: Её же можно будет дня через 3 снова повесить, когда тут потише станет?

Comment: @arelive у меня 12к рейтинга - абсолютно без разницы сколько минусов поставят.

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с `C++11`, в стандарте языка присутствуют [типы с гарантированными длинами](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer):

```
Defined in header <cstdint>
int8_t
int16_t
int32_t
int64_t
  
(optional)
 
signed integer type with width of exactly 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively
with no padding bits and using 2's complement for negative values
(provided only if the implementation directly supports the type)
(typedef)
int_fast8_t
int_fast16_t
int_fast32_t
int_fast64_t
 
fastest signed integer type with width of at least 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively
(typedef)
int_least8_t
int_least16_t
int_least32_t
int_least64_t
 
smallest signed integer type with width of at least 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively
(typedef)
intmax_t
 
maximum-width signed integer type
(typedef)
intptr_t
  
(optional)
 
signed integer type capable of holding a pointer
(typedef)
uint8_t
uint16_t
uint32_t
uint64_t
  
(optional)
 
unsigned integer type with width of exactly 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively
(provided only if the implementation directly supports the type)
(typedef)
uint_fast8_t
uint_fast16_t
uint_fast32_t
uint_fast64_t
 
fastest unsigned integer type with width of at least 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively
(typedef)
uint_least8_t
uint_least16_t
uint_least32_t
uint_least64_t
 
smallest unsigned integer type with width of at least 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively
(typedef)
uintmax_t
 
maximum-width unsigned integer type
(typedef)
uintptr_t
  
(optional)
 
unsigned integer type capable of holding a pointer
(typedef)
```

*Ситуация, когда спустя почти 10 лет после принятия стандарта `C++11` вам нужно использовать компилятор `C++98` выглядит крайне маловероятной и сама по себе - повод для дискуссии. Это примерно как на вебе IE6 поддерживать - можно, но сильно дорого.*